# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $X(S)= \frac{2+2s e^{-2s}+4e^{-4s}}{s^2+4s+3}$ with $\Re(s)>-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Find the inverse Laplace transform of

$$X(S)= \frac{2+2s e^{-2s}+4e^{-4s}}{s^2+4s+3} \qquad \Re(s)>-1$$

I never learned how to use this in class and so I've seen a couple youtube videos however they are too easy and not as complex as this one.

I am aware that this is a step function so therefore it will involve this property: 
$$e^{-cs}F(s)= f(t-c)u(t-c)$$

So far I factored the denominator and separated the numerator and have:

$$\frac{2}{(s+1)(s+3)} + \frac{2se^{-2s}}{(s+1)(s+3)} + e^{4s}\frac{4}{(s+1)(s+3)}$$

Anything like references to problems similar as this one would help me.

Comment: Use partial fractions on each of the $$\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+3)}$$ terms to get it in simplified form. Then use a Laplace transform table to get the result.

Comment: @mattos so you're suggesting I do this? 

$2+2se^{-2s}+4e^{-4s} = A(s+3)+B(s+1)$

Comment: Partial fractions only apply to rational functions (a quotient of polynomials). So, only ignore the exponentials and continue.

Comment: @Azif00 so does this mean I wouldn't be able to use partial fractions in this case? and I would have to use the property $e^{-cs}F(s)= f(t-c)u(t-c)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite your last equation as

$$\frac{2}{(s+1)(s+3)} + e^{-2s}\frac{2s}{(s+1)(s+3)} + e^{-4s}\frac{4}{(s+1)(s+3)}$$

and then do partial fraction decomposition on all three terms. This will form

$$\left(\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{1}{s+3}\right)+e^{-2s}\left(\frac{3}{s+3}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)+e^{-4s}\left(\frac{2}{s+1}-\frac{2}{s+3}\right)$$

from which you can now use the property $e^{-cs}F(s)= \mathcal{L}\{f(t-c)u(t-c)\}(s)$.

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand how to do it now. I will update you when I finish solving the problem! (:

Comment: I got my final answer to be:

$ [e^{-t}-e^{-3t}]u(t) -e^{-(t-2)} u(t-2)+3e^{-3(t-2)}u(t-2)+2e^{-(t-4)}u(t-4)-2e^{-3(t-4)}u(t-4)$ 

Does this look correct?

Comment: I would redo your work - remember that you can check your answer with [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse+laplace+transform+%282%2B2s+e%5E%28-2s%29%2B4e%5E%28-4s%29%29%2F%28s%5E2%2B4s%2B3%29). You don't need to apply the property on $\frac{1}{s+1}$ and $-\frac{1}{s+3}$ - those two terms will produce an inverse transform of $e^{-t}$ and $-e^{-3t}$.

Comment: Yeah I understand that I only used the property $e^{-cs}F(s)= \mathcal{L}\{f(t-c)u(t-c)\}(s)$  for ones that had an exponential. The $\left(\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{1}{s+3}\right)$ has it's own laplace property $ \frac{1}{s+a} = e^{-at}u(t)$ I just grouped them together. Thank you for the help by the way!